# MacBook Pro 15 inch (2011) screen has stripes

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen

My 15 inch MacBook Pro recently has horizontal stripes on the screen.
It looks like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaPt6FHJmtg
It happens randomly and sometimes it gets worse (flickering with horizontal lines,stripes)

Does anyone know what might cause this and how to fix it?

No such issue during the past year...it has just started happening since yesterday.

Comment: I think theres a possibility that ur screen's connector may be dislodged from your motherboard.

Comment: I'd put my money on a hardware issue. Difficult to diagnose on the internet. Could be a loose connection, or the entire screen may need replacing. You'll need to take it into an Apple Store for diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

Take it back to an Apple Store or send it in for repair - that sounds like faulty hardware, and you'll still be in warrantee so they'll repair or replace completely free.

In case they decide to replace it outright (it's fairly new so they may) you'll want to use time machine to snapshot your hard drive for backups.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down Shift + Control and hitting the Eject button. It will make the screen go black for a few seconds, then it will come back, hopefully sans striping.

This will usually fix vertical striping on MacBook Pro screen which is caused by a problem with the backlighting; it may help you too even though your problem looks different.

I saw this video example of vertical striping when I looked at your video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=H62afsEjwZ0&feature=endscreen